# WCF - Return XML Property as Child JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

I am developing  a WCF service . One of the data member is XElement Type. How can I return as XElement data member as a child Json. I  have tried Newtonsoft.Json but its adding black splashes. My DataContract class is below

`[DataContract]`

```
public class Car
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>

    public Car()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets id.
    /// </summary>
     [DataMember]
     public String Id { get; internal set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets name.
     /// </summary>
     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets form.
    /// </summary>
     [DataMember]
     public XElement Form { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: Why do you return XElement and make the life for client harder. (parsing both json and xml). Why is everyhing not in json?

Comment: I don't want to return Form property as xml but xml should be converted into a child json of Form property.

Comment: Then why don't you declare it as `public Form Form` ?

Comment: I am fetching the Form xml from database. Its a very complex xml and not easy to map as an object.